# How to use theme block into custom theme Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template

I have a paid Magento template and it has some features like testimonials blog etc. Also I have a custom theme and I want to use the testimonials feature in custom theme which is another store. I have copy all the files into my custom theme and I am trying to display like below code. But nothing showing.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setTemplate('magentothem/testimonial/sidebar/slider.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If testimonials is a module then it is almost sure that to show testimonials there would be a block class file also.

Using **`core/template`** will not solve your problem. To call **`magentothem/testimonial/sidebar/slider.phtml`** file, you need to use correct block class name in **`createBlock()`**, because in **`slider.phtml`** some functions from block class file would be called.

Please change block class name correctly and let me know if you still find the problem.

Comment: Yes this is a module. i have a block class below.....

class Magentothem_Testimonial_Block_Testimonial extends Mage_Core_Block_Template

Comment: in which file i can check block class.? @mohit

Comment: Block class should be probably **`testimonial/testimonial`**, but for surety, you can check config.xml for block class definition.